# making and using an android library app

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I'd like to know if there is a good way of packaging a library as an Android app that can be used by other Android apps, so that there is only one copy of the library on the phone, and it is used by many separate apps. Some obvious candidates are a numerical library with the Fourier transforms and standard numerical calculus and linear algebra routines, a physics engine, and embedded scripting with your favourite interpreted language. I'm pretty sure those examples are not part of the Android SDK. Even if they are, it is easy to imagine some other kind of library that almost definitely is not, like a library for computing the evolution of cellular automata, or for doing quantum mechanics simulations. I can't seem to find any library apps like this in Google Play, though. Is it because it can't be done? Why not?

Now, I know there are going to be some people asking me why I would want to do this. I'll pre-emptively reply, never mind my reasons for now. Can it be done? Although the advantages of such an approach, as compared to putting a copy of the library in every app that needs it, should be obvious, it is not the subject of this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing a 'library app'.

1. One way is making the project ,and releasing it as a library
   project. eg. is [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). In this method, the library is imported
   as a project by the app developer.
2. Another way of making a library is writing the library, and
   compiling it into a .jar file.Here is another [example](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext).
3. And finally, you can make a proper app(.apk file) and release it
   into the market.In the app, you can create provisions for receiving
   Intents, processing, and sending back Intents. It will besomething like
   communicating between apps.

The last method, however will be slow, as both apps will have to be started, and it will all be a hassle.

Comment: If I understand right, only the third option causes only one copy of the library to be installed on the phone and used by many apps. That is my main concern---that only one copy of the library is installed on the phone.

Comment: yes, you can do it using Intents, but it will be the most complicated of the three. You can also make write to an external folder and have the other apps access it, but even this is not a great way to get it done